# Facebook Access Token doesnt expire, but new documentation says the max is 60 days

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token

From reading the Facebook documentation on access tokens, the maximum lifetime is 60 days.  However, I tested the one below I got through a TEST application of my real application and it says `Never`, meaning it doesnt expire.  Is that correct?  Shouldnt it have an expiration date?  This token gives permission from the user to post to a Facebook page through an application.  This application hasnt been approved yet for the new verification process.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s an Extended Page Token, they are valid forever. See the "Profile ID", that´s the ID of a Page. What you mean is an Extended User Token, those are only valid for 60 days.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/